# How can I build a Gradle project that depends on another, but keep local paths out of version control?

Tags: java, git, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I'm working on organizing two Java projects of mine. Both are using Git for version control. For building them, I'm migrating from simple shell scripts calling `javac` to Gradle. Project C depends on Project L. How can Project C's `build.gradle` find what it needs from Project L? I'd like to avoid checking into version control paths that are local to my computer. I feel I must be missing a better solution than one of these:

- **Add Project L's source path to Project C's source path in `build.gradle`:** that's a local path.
- **Publish Project L to a local repository, and have Project C take a dependency from this repository:** once again I'm specifying a local path; the path of the local repository.
- **Run a remote repository on a server:** I do have a server and a domain, but this seems like overkill.
- **Include a .jar of Project L in Project C:** either I'm checking binaries into version control, which I don't want to do, or I'm ferrying the .jar file around manually as part of the build process.

What's a good solution for this?

Comment: You could create a multi project. There is also a documentation about that: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html Although I don't think the documentation is really good. Anyway you see there how to reference another project by adding project(:bluewale) into you dependencies.

Comment: @romixch in that example, the bluewhale project is in a directory inside the outer project. I want my Project L to also be a separate, standalone project, however. Neither project really "belongs to" the other. What kind of multi project would I be setting up, and how, for this situation? And how would it work with version control?

Comment: The only real way depend on a completely independent project without local paths is to depend on an external repo - the repo doesn't have to be hosted on an external server though, it can be your local .m2

Comment: @RaGe oh, you're talking about [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:maven_local)? Thanks, I hadn't found that when I was searching through the docs. Feel free to post that as an answer. I'm going to try that alongside Michael's submodule solution to see which works best for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle can use your local maven repo. It even uses the same mechanism as Maven to determine the location of the `.m2` folder.

> If a local repository location is defined in a settings.xml, this location will be used. The settings.xml in `USER_HOME/.m2` takes precedence over the settings.xml in `M2_HOME/conf`. If no settings.xml is available, Gradle uses the default location `USER_HOME/.m2/repository`.

As long as you publish your ProjectL artifacts to your local maven, you can consume them from the repo in your ProjectC without using local paths. Just ensure that you build and publish L before C. For more details on publishing to maven repos [see here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).

The local maven repo can be defined in gradle as :

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setup Project L as a sub-module with Git under Project C. Then have Project C treat Project L as a library/precompiled library. One note here is to make sure you never modify the code in the sub-module! If you need to change it make sure you do so in it's separate project. Doing otherwise can and will give you a headache.

Comment: That is to say, make the submodule also be a subproject in a multi-project build. Seems to work. Keeps things in separate repositories, but at the same time I just need to type `./gradlew build` once to build all the jars.